# In Xamarin Forms, can I Bind to a property inside a list of the class I'm showing in listview?

Tags: c#, listview, binding, xamarin.forms

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to develop an app using Xamarin Forms. So far I was able to get most of the answers I needed from here or other tutorials, but this one was not possible.

The idea - I want to show a list of users in a listview. It cell should show his "Name" and the "Value" of a "Topic". But as the user can teach more than one topic, he has a "List", like this:

```
    public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Topic> Topics { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Topics = new List<Topic>();
        Topics.Add(new Topic { TopicName = "English", Value = 150.00 });
        Topics.Add(new Topic { TopicName = "Portuguese", Value = 120.00 });
        Topics.Add(new Topic { TopicName = "Latin", Value = 300.00 });
    }
}

public class Topic
{
    public string TopicName { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

My App, just to show this trial is like this:

```
   public App()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        var template = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCell));
        var users = new List<User>();
        users.Add(new App1.User { Name = "Luizinho" });
        users.Add(new App1.User { Name = "Zezinho" });
        users.Add(new App1.User { Name = "Huguinho" });

        var content = new ContentPage
        {
            Title = "StackFlow_01",
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                    //new Label {Text = "funciona" }
                    new ListView {ItemTemplate = template, ItemsSource = users  }
                    }
            }
        };

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
    }
```

And finally the CustomCell:

```
   public class CustomCell : ViewCell
{
    public CustomCell()
    {
        //instantiate each of our views
        StackLayout cellWrapper = new StackLayout();
        StackLayout horizontalLayout = new StackLayout();
        Label left = new Label();
        Label right = new Label();

        //set bindings
        left.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
        right.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "TopicName");

        //add views to the view hierarchy
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(left);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(right);
        cellWrapper.Children.Add(horizontalLayout);
        View = cellWrapper;
    }
}
```

So, the Name binded to the Left label works fine (and most of the examples around to show something in the first "level" of the class), but how can I bind the Right label to the Value of Portuguese topic? Is it possible?

I know there should be also an IValueConverter, but the biding path is really what I'm not getting.

Answer (score 1):

you can try binding to the first element in the list

```
right.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Topics[0].TopicName");
```

Comment: Nice, works. But if I want to bring the value of "Latin" for example? Is possible to find the specific Topic inside the list?

Comment: I would probably create a new property in your VM that uses a LINQ expression to display the appropriate value

Comment: right.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Topics[0].Value");

Answer (score 0):

Each user has own Topics, so you will need to decide what topic you want to bind to at some point unless you want to bind list of topics to another sub-view list. You probably will need to derive from DataTemplateSelector to make such decision

Comment: Yes, I know which topic i should bind before calling the listview. Suppose it was the Latin topic. How can I target it inside the list?

Comment: right.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Topics[0].Value");